# .htaccess mobile and pc not redirecting properly with querystring

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is how I am currently redirecting the URL from PC to mobile at the moment.

```
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

The problem with the above code is that it cuts ? all querystring out when redirecting to the mobile URL

Now this won't have a problem when rewriting URL from `http://www.example.com/bangkok/` (originally `http://www.example.com/jobs-list-province.php?p_name=bangkok`) to

```
http://m.example.com/bangkok/
```

But it will have problem with URL that requires sending over the querystring, for example:
`http://www.example.com/keyword-search.php?s_keyword=analyst` is redirecting to `http://m.example.com/keyword-search.php` instead of h`ttp://m.example.com/keyword-search.php?s_keyword=analyst`

So I tried to solve the problem by using this code

```
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [QSA,R=301,L]
```

Or this code

```
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

when I use the above code, it has problem with redirecting
`http://www.example.com/bangkok/` in goes to: `http://m.example.com/bangkok/?p_name=bangkok` instead.

How do i rewrite so that
`http://www.example.com/bangkok/` goes to `http://m.example.com/bangkok/` and
`http://www.example.com/keyword-search.php?s_keyword=analyst` goes to `http://m.example.com/keyword-search.php?s_keyword=analyst`

Please see the attached htaccess file for more info. Thank you for your help.

```
#Redirect to www location
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc] 

rewriterule ^(bangkok)$ /jobs-list-province.php?p_name=$1

# Check if mobile=1 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 1
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=1(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:1:%{HTTP_HOST}]

# Check if mobile=0 is set and set cookie 'mobile' equal to 0
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=mobile:0:%{HTTP_HOST}]

 # cookie can't be set and read in the same request so check
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)mobile=0(&|$)
    RewriteRule ^ - [S=1]

    # Check if this looks like a mobile device
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:x-wap-profile} !^$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Profile}       !^$

 # Check if we're not already on the mobile site
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^m\.   
    # Check to make sure we haven't set the cookie before
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !mobile=0(;|$) [NC]          

    RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Put bangkok rule at the bottom of .htaccess?

Comment: I tried that. it give the same results

Comment: OK, let me read the question again :), more careful this time

Comment: @DusanBajic 's suggestion should have worked. Can you please share how you moved your rules around?

Comment: I move rewriterule ^(bangkok)$ /jobs-list-province.php?p_name=$1 to the bottom of the file. but again on mobile it goes to http://m.example.com/keyword-search.php without the query string

Comment: move it to the bottom **and** remove the question mark from previous rule

Comment: it works now! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things:

1. (Which you already tried) is to remove question mark from

   `RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [QSA,R=301,L]`

   since it is preventing the query string to be passed through unchanged.
2. Move this rule:

   `rewriterule ^(bangkok)$ /jobs-list-province.php?p_name=$1`

   to the bottom, since you don't want your rules to mix. First handle redirect to mobile site, then check for `/bangkok` rewrite